# SQL Oracle - Want to add another "like" condition to a case

Tags: sql, oracle

```
I have the following query:

Select 
Count(Distinct Case When Play.Uuid Like ('i~%') Then Tap.Player_Id End) As Tapjoy_Ios
From
Player_Tapjoy Tap
Inner Join 
Player Play 
On 
Tap.Player_Id = Play.Player_Id
Where 
Trunc(Tap.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
```

I want to add another like constrain so that the result comes out where play.uuid like ('i~%' or 'ti~%')..but that doesn't seem to work. How could I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two full `LIKE` clauses connected by a logical `OR`, each having both the left and right sides of the `LIKE` keyword (column on the left, string value on the right).

```
count(Distinct Case When (Play.Uuid Like 'i~%') OR (Play.Uuid LIKE 'ti~%') Then Tap.Player_Id End) As Tapjoy_Ios
```

You could also do this with a single [`REGEXP_LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm), using the regular expressiong `^t?i~.+`:

```
count(Distinct Case When REGEXP_LIKE(Play.Uuid, '^t?i~.+') Then Tap.Player_Id End) As Tapjoy_Ios
```

- `^` is the start of the string
- `t?` is an optional `t`
- `i~` is literal
- `.+` is any remaining characters, equivalent to `%` in a regular `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an `OR`:

```
Select Count(Distinct Case When Play.Uuid Like ('i~%')
                          OR Play.Uuid Like ('ti~%') 
                      Then Tap.Player_Id End) As Tapjoy_Ios
From Player_Tapjoy Tap
Inner Join Player Play 
  On Tap.Player_Id = Play.Player_Id
Where Trunc(Tap.Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answers are correct, you're applying the condition at the wrong level. You normally want to FILTER the data for better performance, although the LIKE clause here makes it less significant.

```
    Select Count(Distinct Tap.Player_Id) As Tapjoy_Ios
      From Player_Tapjoy Tap
Inner Join Player Play On Tap.Player_Id = Play.Player_Id
     Where Tap.Create_Dtime >= To_Date('2012-Jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
       And (Play.Uuid Like ('i~%') OR Play.Uuid Like ('ti~%'))
```

As written in the question, it was processing all rows and fizzing on the ones that don't match the LIKE pattern(s).  You also don't want to run functions against columns, which doesn't allow indexes to be used - I have updated your date filter. You didn't really need the TRUNC.